# Looping over @FetchRequest in init()

Tags: swift, swiftui

This should be an easy question, hope for some quick help (I'm new at swift)

I have a View which performs a @FetchRequest, this part works great. What I want to do, though, is do some stuff with each item. However, if I try to do a forEach, I get the following error:

> Referencing instance method 'forEach' requires wrapped value of type 'FetchedResults'

Here is my code:

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.title)]
    )var allItems: FetchedResults<Item>

    init() {
        /* error */
        self._allItems.forEach( { item in
            performFunction(item: item)
        })
    }
}
```

How do I properly loop over all of the _allItems in my init function?

Thanks

Comment: You don't. You shouldn't do any heavy lifting like this in the `init` of a `View`, which may get called _many_ times. Instead, use `task` or `onAppear`

Comment: Fair enough. I thought there was a conventional way to do this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It isn’t available/loaded on init

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to transform an item then you need to move it to body, e.g.

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.title)]
    )var allItems: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: View {
        ForEach(allItems) { item in 
            MySubview(result: performFunction(item: item))
        }
    }
}
```